# Error deploying vue app using any type of deployment

Tags: vue.js, deployment, web-deployment

I have only deployed a couple small apps before and I am still newer to deploying apps in general.

I created this app by following a course and have recently finished the project. The course did not provide instructions on how to deploy the app. I have used Firebase hosting a couple times and am also somewhat familiar with Heroku. Regardless, it all seems pretty straight forward after following documentation.

I first tried Firebase hosting since that is what I am most familiar with. Spent some time with that with no luck, then tried heroku, then netlify, then NOW. Every single one of them had issues without any real information on them.

- NOW says `deployement failed` with no logs.
- Firebase hosting doesn't seem to be logging any errors, it builds a blank page.
- Netlify says `page not found` after deployment and Heroku was something similar.

I am 100% open to getting this simple app deployed using any approach at all (preferably the easiest one).

Since I am following documentation and there doesn't seem to be any errors being logged, I'm completely stumped and am not sure what to do.

I realize I might not be providing the most helpful information to solve this issue, although I do have my full repo here:

https://github.com/SIeep/austin-pizza

Would anyone be kind enough to look over my repo and see what the issue might be? Or even point me in the right direction?

Please let me know if I need to provide any additional information.

Thanks!

Comment: What's command/script do you use to deploy?

Comment: I was following the documentation of each of the different deployment options and following their instructions. Let me know if i misunderstood your question.Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

missing entry file or file path problem ?

Try to find out which stage the problem is at first.

Compare this and last successful Firebase Configuration（dependency path），

Compare this and the last build dist file （not detail code,just File structure）

compare webpack.config.js
（app can run well locally,so i think it wouldn't because of the problem with the app's own code）

Comment: That's fair -- I suppose I will just have to dig deeper and compare with other projects. Thank you!